# Performing a calculation for two list

Tags: r

I have a data frame in `R`

```
rank=c(0,0,0,1:9,0,0,0,0,0,1:7)
group = rep(1:2,each=12)
d <- data.frame(rank, group)

d_sp <- split(d, d$group)
r <- lapply(d_sp, function(x) sample(1:tail(x$rank, n=1), 6) )
```

I want to write the following two line codes without writing one line code for each list:

```
 d_sp[[1]]$samp_rank1 <- d_sp[[1]]$rank %in% r[[1]]
 d_sp[[2]]$samp_rank2 <- d_sp[[2]]$rank %in% r[[2]]
```

But `Map("%in%", d_sp$rank, r)` does not work for that purpose. How is to do this?

Moreover it will be very helpful if I do not need to split the data frame and doing the same work within each group.

Comment: Is this what you want `sample_rank <- ave(rank, group, FUN = function(x){
    r <- sample(1:x[length(x)], 6);
    x %in% r
})`

Comment: @RonakShah yes, so I have to do `samp_rank <- Map(function(x, y) x$rank %in% y, d, r)' ; `d <- Map("cbind", d, samp_rank)`. But I like not my splitting technique

Comment: @mt1022 it's brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to make the data.frame and split, you can try `ave`, which is similar to the `group_by` then `mutate` logic of `dplyr`:

```
sample_rank <- ave(rank, group, FUN = function(x){
    r <- sample(1:x[length(x)], 6)
    x %in% r
})
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `Map` on the two lists and extract only the `rank` column of `d_sp` and add a new column for every list using `cbind`.

```
Map(function(a, b) cbind(a, samp_rank = a$rank %in% b), d_sp, r)

#$`1`
#   rank group samp_rank
#1     0     1     FALSE
#2     0     1     FALSE
#3     0     1     FALSE
#4     1     1      TRUE
#5     2     1      TRUE
#6     3     1     FALSE
#7     4     1     FALSE
#8     5     1      TRUE
#9     6     1      TRUE
#10    7     1      TRUE
#11    8     1     FALSE  
#12    9     1      TRUE

#$`2`
#   rank group samp_rank
#13    0     2     FALSE
#14    0     2     FALSE
#15    0     2     FALSE
#16    0     2     FALSE
#17    0     2     FALSE
#18    1     2      TRUE
#19    2     2      TRUE
#20    3     2      TRUE
#21    4     2     FALSE
#22    5     2      TRUE
#23    6     2      TRUE
#24    7     2      TRUE
```